# Using implicit differentiation to find a line that is tangent to a curve at a point

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

A few days ago I [asked](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/1837) about using differentiation to find a line that is tangent to a curve at a given point. [J.M.](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/50) provided a very elegant way to solve these kinds of problems in Mathematica.

Now I'd like to find a line that is tangent to $x^2+xy+y^2=3$ at $(1,1)$ using implicit differentiation.

To find the slope at $(1,1)$ I used this code:

```
x^2 + x y[x] + y[x]^2 == 3;
D[%, x];
% /. x -> 1;
% /. y[1] -> 1;
Reduce[%, y'[1]]
```

which yields:

```
y'[1] == -1
```

Now to find the equation of the line:

```
y[x] - y[a] == y'[a] (x - a);
% /. a -> 1;
% /. y[1] -> 1;
% /. y'[1] -> -1;
Reduce[%, y[x]]
```

which yields:

```
y[x] == 2 - x
```

The answer is correct, but of course the method is much less elegant than for the case of non-implicit differentiation. Is there a better way than the one given above to solve the problem?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I'm not sure the implicit case allows for a solution as elegant as the explicit case; here is what I'd do, however:

```
eq = x^2 + x y + y^2 == 3; pt = {1, 1};
With[{m = (Dt[y, x] /. First[Solve[Dt[eq, x], Dt[y, x]]]) /.
            Thread[{x, y} -> pt]}, 
           Collect[m (x - First[pt]) + Last[pt], x, Simplify]]
2 - x
```

As you can see, this assumes a point `pt` on the implicitly-defined curve `eq` is already known; if not, a preliminary application of `Solve[]` is necessary.

---

Prompted by Michael's answer, I managed to figure out a second solution, based on the properties of the [gradient](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Gradient.html) of a function of two variables (here computed as [`D[f, {{x, y}}]`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/D.html)):

```
eq = x^2 + x y + y^2 == 3; pt = {1, 1};
Expand[(D[Subtract @@ eq, {{x, y}}] /. Thread[{x, y} -> pt]).({x, y} - pt)] == 0
-6 + 3 x + 3 y == 0
```

This also requires that both coordinates of `pt` are already known, as in the first method.

---

**Warning:**

It must be noted, however, that both approaches given so far will fail spectacularly if the point being considered is in fact a [singular point](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SingularPoint.html) of the given curve (e.g. the [(cru)node](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Crunode.html) at the point $(0,0)$ of the [folium of Descartes](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/FoliumofDescartes.html) $x^3+y^3=3xy$). There are special techniques to attack cases like this (based on the clever evaluation of an appropriate limit), but I shall not say anything further about them in this answer.

Comment: Thank you @J.M.. I also decided to explore using a program to solve this sort of problem. I've posted a separate answer illustrating this approach.

Comment: "There are special techniques to attack cases like this..." - which I finally decided to demonstrate in my other answer.

Answer (score 9):

For giggles, here's a solution that a.) works only on algebraic curves, and b.) **avoids calculus** at the expense of having to solve simultaneous equations (via `GroebnerBasis[]` and `Eliminate[]`):

```
eq = x^2 + x y + y^2 == 3; pt = {1, 1};
fac = Apply[Times, 
        Power @@@ 
          DeleteCases[FactorSquareFreeList[
          First[GroebnerBasis[
                 Append[Thread[{x, y} == pt + {a, b} u], eq],
                              {u, a, b}, {x, y}]]],
                 {_?NumericQ, 1} | {u, _Integer}]] /. u -> 0;
ta = Eliminate[Append[Thread[{x, y} == pt + {a, b} u], fac == 0], {a, b, u}]

2 - y == x

ContourPlot[{eq, ta} // Evaluate, {x, -3, 3}, {y, -3, 3}, 
    Epilog -> {AbsolutePointSize[5], Point[pt]}, PlotPoints -> 85]
```

[image: tangent to an ellipse]

Here's the method applied to finding the tangent of the [trifolium](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Trifolium.html) $(x^2 + y^2)^2=y(3x^2 - y^2)$ at the point $\left(\dfrac{1-\sqrt{3}}{4},-\dfrac{1+\sqrt{3}}{4}\right)$:

```
eq = (x^2 + y^2)^2 == y (3 x^2 - y^2);
pt = {(1 - Sqrt[3])/4, -(1 + Sqrt[3])/4};
fac = Apply[Times, 
        Power @@@ 
          DeleteCases[FactorSquareFreeList[
          First[GroebnerBasis[
                 Append[Thread[{x, y} == pt + {a, b} u], eq],
                              {u, a, b}, {x, y}]]],
                 {_?NumericQ, 1} | {u, _Integer}]] /. u -> 0;
ta = Eliminate[Append[Thread[{x, y} == pt + {a, b} u], fac == 0], {a, b, u}]

1 - 2 Sqrt[3] + 8 y - 5 Sqrt[3] y == 11 x

ContourPlot[{eq, ta} // Evaluate, {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}, 
    Epilog -> {AbsolutePointSize[5], Point[pt]}, PlotPoints -> 85]
```

[image: tangent to a trifolium]

Nicely enough, the method still works even at the [singular points](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SingularPoint.html) that I warned about in my previous answer:

```
eq = (x^2 + y^2)^2 == y (3 x^2 - y^2); pt = {0, 0};
fac = Apply[Times, 
        Power @@@ 
          DeleteCases[FactorSquareFreeList[
          First[GroebnerBasis[
                 Append[Thread[{x, y} == pt + {a, b} u], eq],
                              {u, a, b}, {x, y}]]],
                 {_?NumericQ, 1} | {u, _Integer}]] /. u -> 0;
ta = Eliminate[Append[Thread[{x, y} == pt + {a, b} u], fac == 0], {a, b, u}];
ContourPlot[{eq, ta} // Evaluate, {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}, 
    Epilog -> {AbsolutePointSize[5], Point[pt]}, PlotPoints -> 85]
```

[image: trifolium tangents at triple point]

where as you can see, all three tangents at the point $(0,0)$ were found.

Comment: ...and if you want to learn more, see [this book](http://www.cs.amherst.edu/~dac/iva.html).

Comment: If you like J.M.'s approach for algebraic curves, you may like the MathOverflow [question](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/77175) titled "Taking 'Zooming in on a point of a graph' seriously" and Jack Huizenga's answer.

Answer (score 6):

I'm not sure if you're aware of this, but if you have a curve of the form $f(x,y)=\text{constant}$, then the gradient of $f$ at some point $(x_0,y_0)$ on the curve will be perpendicular to the curve at that point. Therefore, the slope of the line tangent to `x^2+x y+y^2==3` at the point `pt={1,1}` is equal to

```
pt = {1, 1};
eq = x^2 + x y + y^2;
slope = -D[eq, x]/D[eq, y] /. Thread[{x, y} -> pt];
```

And the tangent line is equal to

```
line[x_] := pt[[2]] + (x - pt[[1]]) slope
```

To show that the line is indeed tangent at `{1,1}`:

```
Show[Plot[line[x], {x, 0, 2}], 
  ContourPlot[f[x, y] == 3, {x, 0, 2}, {y, 0, 2}]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: This is essentially my second solution, but given in an explicit form.

Answer (score 5):

If you are satisfied with a function which applies only to algebraic curves, there is an alternative approach which starts by homogenizing the algebraic curve.  See for example the Wikipedia [article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tangent#Equations) on "Tangent".  To homogenize the equation $x^2+xy+y^2-3=0$, we can try

```
Numerator@Together@ReplaceAll[x^2 + x y + x^2 - 3, {x -> x/z, y -> y/z}]
```

So the homogeneous equation looks like `x^2 + x y + y^2 - 3 z^2`.  Let this polynomial be `g`.  One equation of the tangent line is given by

$g_{x}(x_{0},y_{0},1) \cdot x + g_{y}(x_{0},y_{0},1) \cdot y + g_{z}(x_{0},y_{0},1)= 0$

We can compute each of the partial derivatives using `D`, so for example $g_{x}(1,1,1)$ is given by

```
D[g, x] /. {x -> 1, y -> 1, z -> 1}
```

Putting everything together, we get one equation of the line passing through $(1,1)$ which is tangent to the curve $x^2+xy+y^2-3=0$:

$3x+3y-6=0$.

My original goal was to find an analog of J.M.'s elegant [solution](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1837/281) to an earlier version of the problem which eschews the use of `Reduce`.  I have not been able to put together a nice, short code like J.M.'s using this alternative approach though.

Comment: What is a good way to take the derivative of a function so that the output is also a function?  It would be nice if I could do something like `D[g,x][1,1,1]` and get the partial derivative evaluated at $(1,1,1)$.  Using `ReplaceAll` just does not seem right.

Comment: `g = x^2 + x y + y^2 - 3 z^2; (Derivative[##][Function[{x, y, z}, Evaluate[g]]][1, 1, 1] & @@@ IdentityMatrix[3]).{x, y, 1} == 0` works nicely, I think.

Comment: @J.M. I am amazed at how quickly you come up with such elegant codes.

Comment: I upvoted your answer, BTW. :) I distinctly recall a more automatic method for performing such homogenizations on algebraic curves based on the properties of Gröbner bases, but I need to check my notes to be certain.

Answer (score 3):

I've written a program to solve this sort of problem:

```
Tangent[ax_, ay_, eq_, x_, y_] :=
 Module[{rule, slope},
  rule = {a -> ax, y[a] -> ay};
  slope = ToRules[Reduce[D[eq, x] /. x -> a /. rule, y'[a] /. rule]];
  Reduce[y[x] - y[a] == y'[a] (x - a) /. rule /. slope, y[x]]]
```

To solve the above:

```
Tangent[1, 1, x^2 + x y[x] + y[x]^2 == 3, x, y]
```

which yields:

```
y[x] == 2 - x
```

`Tangent` also appears to work on problems involving explicit differentiation.

The parameters to `Tangent` are as follows:

- `ax` and `ay` indicate the point at which the line is tangent to the
  curve.
- `eq` is the equation of the curve.
- `x` and `y` are the independent and dependent variables.