# How to do implicit differentiation in Mathematica?

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, implicit

I have an equation which is

```
K^(1/2)*L^(1/2)-(K+L) = 24
```

but I don't know how to do implicit differentiation to find dK/dL because I only know how to do the normal differentiation and the partial one.

Can anyone help? Thanks much!

Comment: Have a look at `Dt`.

Comment: Welcome! I suggest the following:   
1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by **answering questions** in your area of expertise. 
2) Take the [tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour) and check the [faqs](http://goo.gl/kQNRaS)!   
3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)!

Comment: Related: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/1945/using-implicit-differentiation-to-find-a-line-that-is-tangent-to-a-curve-at-a-po

Answer (score 24):

`Dt[]`, the total derivative, does what you're looking for.

```
Dt[K^(1/2)*L^(1/2)-(K+L)==24,L]
```

> ```
> -1+Sqrt[K]/(2 Sqrt[L])-Dt[K,L]+(Sqrt[L] Dt[K,L])/(2 Sqrt[K])==0
> ```

```
Solve[%,Dt[K,L]]
```

> ```
> {{Dt[K,L]->(Sqrt[K] (Sqrt[K]-2 Sqrt[L]))/((2 Sqrt[K]-Sqrt[L]) Sqrt[L])}}
> ```

Comment: would you also use Dt to handle a derivative of a piecewise function that has some part that is defined by a numerical approximation (FindRoot) and so in order to take the derivative we would require to use the implicit function theorem for that part? Like in here:https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/165472/implicit-function-derivative-of-piecewise-function-that-has-a-findroot-in-one-o

Answer (score 16):

Finally, [`ImplicitD`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ImplicitD.html) is introduced in *v13.1*:

```
ImplicitD[K^(1/2)*L^(1/2) - (K + L) == 24, K, L]
```

[image]

Answer (score 9):

[image]
[image]

With k = k(L) we can write:

```
f[L_, k_] = Sqrt[k] Sqrt[L] - (k + L) - 24;
df = -D[f[L, k], L]/D[f[L, k], k] // Simplify
```

[image]

Answer (score 8):

To do this, you must use `k` as a function of `L`. Where it's wise to use lower case `k`.

> Note that K is a default generic name for a summation index in a symbolic sum.

```
eqn = k[L]^(1/2)*L^(1/2) - (k[L] + L) == 24
Solve[D[eqn, L], k'[L]]
```

> `{{Derivative[1][k][L] -> ((2 Sqrt[L] - Sqrt[k[L]]) Sqrt[k[L]])/(
>      Sqrt[L] (Sqrt[L] - 2 Sqrt[k[L]]))}}`

Answer (score 5):

Here is a simple method I use. The following module performs implicit differentiation of an equation of two variables in a conventional format, i.e., with independent variable of the form x (or some other symbol), and dependent variable of the form y (or some other symbol). It converts the dependent variable to the form f [x] and calculates the derivative f' [x] if it exists, and then converts the symbols back to the input format and outputs the solution.

```
implicitD[lhs_, rhs_, indVar_, depVar_] :=
 Module[{ls, rs, f, R},
  ls = lhs /. depVar -> f[indVar];
  rs = rhs /. depVar -> f[indVar];
  R = Solve[D[ls, indVar] == D[rs, indVar], f'[indVar]][[1, 1]];
  R /. {f[indVar] -> depVar, f'[indVar] -> depVar'}
  ]
```

For example, to differentiate 3(x^2 + y^2)^2 == 100 x y, use module as follows:

```
implicitD[3(x^2 + y^2)^2, 100 x y, x, y]
```

Returns:

y' -> (-3x^3 + 25y - 3x y^2)/(-25x + 3x^2 y + 3y^3)

For your question: differentiate: K^(1/2)*L^(1/2) - (K + L)
Use the same method:

```
implicitD[K^(1/2)*L^(1/2) - (K + L), 24, L, K]
```

Your result should look like this image:

[image: outputEquation]