# How to evaluate derivative for implicit

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

If $x = \frac{1}{2}y(y^2-3)$, how do I use Mathematica to evaluate $\frac{\text{d}y}{\text{d}x}$ at the point where $y=0$? Doing `f[y_] = 1/2*y*(y^2 - 3)` and then `D[y, f[y]] /. y -> 0` gives the errors "$\frac{1}{2}y(-3+y^2)$ is not a valid variable" and "$0$ is not a valid variable".

Comment: Maybe you mean:  D[f[y], y] /. y -> 0 ?

Comment: But as $x=f(y)$, that would give me $\frac{\text{d}x}{\text{d}y}$, whereas I want $\frac{\text{d}y}{\text{d}x}$.

Comment: So then maybe you are looking for: D[InverseFunction[f][y], y] /. y -> 0?

Comment: Yes, that works in this case.

Comment: Duplicate: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/124399/how-to-do-implicit-differentiation-in-mathematica

Comment: `In[144]:= 1/D[1/2*y*(y^2 - 3), y] /. y -> 0

Out[144]= -(2/3)` (proof of method uses chain rule).

Answer (score 6):

This is basically the same approach as coolwaters, just packaged up differently. You can use [`Dt`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Dt):

```
Dt[x == 1/2 y (y^2-3), x]
```

> 1 == y^2 Dt[y, x] + 1/2 (-3 + y^2) Dt[y, x]

Using Solve, and then replacing `y` with 0:

```
Dt[y, x] /. First @ Solve[Dt[x == 1/2 y (y^2-3), x], Dt[y, x]] /. y->0
```

> -2/3

Answer (score 3):

One approach is to find an explicit representation for the inverse function, and then take the derivative:

```
D[InverseFunction[f][y], y] /. y -> 0
```

Answer (score 3):

Consider `y` as a function of `x`:

```
d = D[x == 1/2 y[x] (y[x]^2 - 3), x]
(* 1 == y[x]^2 y'[x] + 1/2 (-3 + y[x]^2) y'[x] *)
```

Replace `y[x]` by 0:

```
d /. y[x] -> 0
(* 1 == -(3/2) y'[x] *)
```

Which solves as `y'[x] -> -(2/3)`. Note this is only valid if the original equation has a solution after letting `y == 0`.