# Finding the 1st three derivatives of a function and plotting all four curves

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

> Plot all three; the function, its derivative and its tangent line at a given point. Then, find the second and third derivative of the function.

```
f(x)= x^(3)-2x, x= -1
```

I know its something like this, but I kept getting the wrong answer or error messages.

```
f[x_] := [[x^(3)-2x, x],{x-> -1}]
f'[]
f''[]
f'''[]
Plot[{f[x],f'[x],f''[x], f'''[x]},{x},PlotLegends->"Expressions"]
```

Not sure about the tangent line

Comment: Have you seen [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/1837)?

Comment: I tried making some sense but its looks confusing. All i know is how to find the slope not the tangent line:    ReplaceAll[D[x^3 - 2 x, x], {x -> -1}]   
        I have have issues with the Plotting all the equation in one graph.

Comment: i figured out the tangent line equation, im getting errors plotting the graph.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I like David Stork's answer, but I also think an answer more focused on the specific example give by the OP might be helpful.

The given function

```
f[x_] := x^3 - 2 x
```

Its 1st derivative

```
d1F[x_] = f'[x]
```

> `-2 + 3 x^2`

Note that I use `Set` ( `=` ), not `SetDelayed` ( `:=` ), because I want the `d1F` to the specific derivative of `x^3 - 2 x` and not just a synonym for `f'[x]`.

The tangent line

At a given point, say `x0`, the tangent line is the line passing through `{x0, f[x0]}` having slope `f'[x0]` and is given by

```
f[x0] + f'[x0] (x - x0)
```

That the this expression is a line is obvious because it is a linear function of `x`. That it passes through `{x0, f[x0]}` is trivial because when `x` is set to `x0`, the 2nd term is 0. Further, since a line's slope is the multiplier of its independent variable and `x` is multiplied by `f'[x0]`, the line has the required slope. So a function giving the tangent line of `f` when `x == x0` can be defined by

```
tangentF[x_, x0_] = f[x0] + f'[x0] (x - x0) // Simplify
```

> `-2 x0^3 + x (-2 + 3 x0^2)`

Again, I use `Set` ( `=` ), not `SetDelayed` ( `:=` ), because I want the tangent function to be specific to `f`.

Now we have everything we need to make the plot.

```
With[{x0 = -1},
  Plot[{f[x], d1F[x], tangentF[x, x0]}, {x, -2, 1},
    Epilog -> {Red, PointSize[Large], Point[{x0, f[x0]}]},
    AspectRatio -> 1,
    PlotRange -> {-4, 4},
    PlotLegends -> {"Function", "Derivative", "Tangent Line"}]]
```

[image: plot]

As for the two higher derivatives, they are given by

```
f''[x]
```

> `6 x`

and

```
f'''[x]
```

> `6`

Comment: That’s perfect ! I think this explains more throughly since I’m still a noob . I really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 2):

```
    ff[myfun_, x_, x0_] := 
 Plot[{Evaluate[myfun@x], 
       Evaluate[myfun'@x], 
       Evaluate[myfun''@x], 
       Evaluate[myfun'''@x],
       Evaluate[x myfun'[x0] + myfun[x0] - x0 myfun'[x0]]}, 
  {x, 0, 4},
  PlotLegends -> "Expressions",
  PlotStyle -> {Red, Green, Blue, Orange, {Dashed, Purple}},
  Epilog -> {PointSize[0.02], Red, Point[{x0, myfun@x0}]}];

ff[Sin[#] &, x, 1]
```

[image]

or

```
ff[Sin[#^2/5] &, x, 1]
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you David .