# How do I draw a function along with a particular tangent line at a specific point?

Tags: plotting, calculus-and-analysis, functions

I would like to draw a function (x/x^2+1), and at a certain point, i'd like to draw a dot along with the tangent line at that specific point.

what I have tried is the following:

```
Plot[{function[x], function'[x]}, {x, -5, 5}, AxesLabel -> {x, y} LabelStyle -> Direction[Black, Bold]]
```

However, this plots the original function f(x) and f'(x) simultaneously; how can I achieve the desired result?

Comment: Duplicate: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/87375/plotting-the-tangent-of-a-curve, which is a duplicate of https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/18090/sliding-a-tangent-line-along-a-curve

Comment: Also [this thread](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/1837).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
function[x_] := x/(x^2 + 1);

x0 = 1/2; 
Plot[{function[x], function[x0] + function'[x0] (x - x0)}, {x, -5, 5}, 
 AxesLabel -> {x, y}, LabelStyle -> Direction[Black, Bold], 
 Mesh -> {{x0}}, MeshStyle -> Directive[Red, PointSize[Large]]]
```

[image]

Comment: Hey thanks! I'm trying to plot this at point 45, but it doesn't seem to plot the tangent at that point; instead the tangent is on a completely different line with two dots?

Comment: @Jaigus, there was a typo; fixed now. `Mesh -> {{1/2}}` should be  `Mesh -> {{x0}}`.

Comment: Thanks alot, this works great.

Comment: Alternatively: `Plot[{function[x], Normal[Series[function[x], {x, x0, 1}]]} // Evaluate, {x, -5, 5}]`.

Comment: @J.M.iscomputer-less, that's much neater.